# Css: blocking properties from other scripts

Tags: css

I've been working on a project at work where the each page has its own css file. However, these pages share some css classes' names, .PSBOTTOMLINE, but each script has different properties for it depending on the page.

However, I've been getting some problems because my pages are getting properties from similar classes from other scripts, besides using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/Project/styles/ProjectCss7.css">`
to specify what script should be used.

For example, in that one script, i have this class:

```
.PSBOTTOMLINE {
vertical-align: bottom;
margin-left: -2px;
background: url(/Content/Project/images/PT_TAB_BOTTOM_LINE_SD_CSS_1.JPG) repeat-x scroll bottom left transparent;}
```

However, this is being imported from script Css2:

```
.PSBOTTOMLINE {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
height: 2px;}
```

How can I prevent properties from being "imported", and make sure my page use only the properties from the appropriate script? I've been renaming the classes but was hoping for a more intelligent way.

Comment: Not an answer, because it won't solve the problem, but, why does each page have its own stylesheet? That sort of defeats the point of *having* stylesheets.

Comment: The Css is likely being cached and because the class names are the same the cached version is being used. You probably want a bit of javascript on page pre-load that clears the cache.

Comment: As Nick Bailey sais your CSS structure is weird. Normally you should use CSS selectors in combination with HTML to add styling to all of your pages. Also the last CSS rule read by browser is the used one but that is not probably your problem.

Comment: @bilpor, and how could I do that?

NickBailey i agree, but thats how the greater minds want it to be.

Comment: no javascript in the page header add : `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />`

Comment: @bilpor that made no difference, sorry.

Comment: I'm still sure it will be a caching issue, Take a look at this Link https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: I'm in developer mode and have cache turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite some properties in the page css file like this

```
margin-left: 0px !important;
```

Comment: That would work when both classes have that property. However, my main issue is properties not present in one class being imported from the others.